# Background job in bash automatically stopped even though it should not work

Tags: linux, bash, multithreading

I have the following script, allowing me to port-forward containers from my kubernetes cluster and then start the UI locally.

```sh
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/gql-api-exposer 8080:8080 &
kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/kratos-public 8090:80 &
yarn dev
```

The thing that confuses me is that the port-forwards do not keep running when I stop the script via ctrl-c. Why is this the case? Why don't I need something like `trap 'pkill $(jobs -p)' EXIT` ?

Answer (score 1):

By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> you are sending a `SIGINT` to the process in foreground, which `bash` will forward signal to the child processes.

You can mitigate that as following:

```
#using disown
command & disown

#using nohup
nohup command &
```

Comment: Thanks! But when do I need the `trap 'pkill $(jobs -p)' EXIT `?